# How to prevent attributes from being prefixed in the output?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have XSLT code that translates from one XML format to another. The source document has elements with namespace prefixes. The target document that is output should only contain elements and attributes without the namespace prefixes. However, I have a scenario where attributes generated in the target document are prepended with a namespace

For example:

```
<PaymentForm otc:CardNumber="xxxxx">
```

I would like to know in what situations can this happen and what measures can be taken to prevent it. Note: I have added the processor directive exclude-result-prefixes to the XSLT code which I had presumed would ensure that elements and attributes would not be prefixed.

All advice and/or recommendations greatly appreciated.

In the case of above, I have the following XSLT code snippet that generates the target document:

```
<xsl:template match="otc:PaymentCard" mode="profile">
        <xsl:variable name="cardnumber" select="otc:CardNumber"/>           
        <xsl:variable name="expiry" select="otc:ExpiryDate"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cardtype" select="otc:CardType"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cardholder" select="otc:CardHolderName"/>
        <PaymentCard>
            <xsl:attribute name="ExpireDate"><xsl:value-of select="$expiry"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="CardNumber"><xsl:value-of select="$cardnumber"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="CardType"><xsl:value-of select="$cardtype"/></xsl:attribute>
            <CardHolderName><xsl:value-of select="$cardholder"/></CardHolderName>
        </PaymentCard>          
    </xsl:template>
```

In this specific case, the ExpireDate is transformed correctly and the CardNumber and CardType are transformed with the otc namespace prefixed.

e.g.

```
<otc:PaymentForm>
  <otc:PaymentCard ExpireDate="2022-12-31" otc:CardNumber="************1111" otc:CardType="VI">
  <otc:CardHolderName>Mr. J. Banks</otc:CardHolderName>
 </otc:PaymentCard>
</otc:PaymentForm>
```

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but we need more information to be able to help. Please edit your post and include your XSLT stylesheet and minimal samples of XML input and output ("minimal" in the sense of reducing complexity but preserving the problem you are facing).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know in what situations can this happen

1. When you create an attribute as part of a literal result element, and use a namespace prefix:

   `<example otc:att="x"/>`
2. When you use xsl:attribute and include a prefix in the name

   `<xsl:attribute name="otc:att"/>`
3. When you use xsl:attribute and use the namespace attribute

   `<xsl:attribute name="att" namespace="http://otc.com/example"/>`
4. When you copy a namespaced attribute from the source document using `<xsl:copy/>` or `<xsl:copy-of/>`

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know in what situations can this happen

It can happen when you copy an attribute that has a namespace. Copying copies the namespace, too - and the prefix marks the attribute as belonging to the namespace bound to this prefix somewhere in your output.

> I have added the processor directive exclude-result-prefixes to the
>   XSLT code which I had presumed would ensure that elements and
>   attributes would not be prefixed.

No, that's not what `exclude-result-prefixes` does.

> what measures can be taken to prevent it.

Instead of copying, you need to create a **new** attribute with the same local-name and value as the source one - in the same way you have done for the elements, I presume.

Comment: Added sample code snippet to question. I create the new attributes with the local names and values.

Comment: @glawlor Please post your input, too - so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @glawlor And while you're at it, all other templates that have the same mode - if not the whole stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

> the ExpireDate is transformed correctly and the CardNumber and
>   CardType are transformed with the otc namespace prefixed

I cannot reproduce this.

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<otc:PaymentCard xmlns:otc="httP://www.otc.com">
    <otc:CardNumber>12345</otc:CardNumber>
    <otc:ExpiryDate>12-02-2014</otc:ExpiryDate>
    <otc:CardType>Master</otc:CardType>
    <otc:CardHolderName>Johnson</otc:CardHolderName>
</otc:PaymentCard>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:otc="httP://www.otc.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="otc:PaymentCard">
        <PaymentCard>
            <xsl:attribute name="ExpireDate"><xsl:value-of select="otc:ExpiryDate"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="CardNumber"><xsl:value-of select="otc:CardNumber"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="CardType"><xsl:value-of select="otc:CardType"/></xsl:attribute>
            <CardHolderName><xsl:value-of select="otc:CardHolderName"/></CardHolderName>
        </PaymentCard>          
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

As you can see, nothing is prefixed. Tested with Saxon 9.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PaymentCard ExpireDate="12-02-2014" CardNumber="12345" CardType="Master">
   <CardHolderName>Johnson</CardHolderName>
</PaymentCard>
```